# In a grails GSP, how do you escape GString expressions

Tags: grails, gsp

I need to write some javascript in a GSP that contains the character sequence ${} (OpenLayers Style - Attribute Replacement Syntax). Unfortunatly, this is also the syntax for a groovy gstring expression. How do I escape it so that Grails does not interpret the character sequence as a gstring. I have tried '\' but that did not work.

Comment: Did you try this <%='${test}'%>... note the single quotes

Comment: Show an example of what you tried. '\' doesn't show the context.

Answer (score 5):

The way I usually do this is

```
${'${test}'}
```

or alternatively

```
${'$'}{test}
```

Note the use of *single* rather than *double* quotes - `${"${test}"}` would not work because the inner `${}` would be interpreted as a GString rather than a literal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alert("\$\{test\}");
```

Output:

```
${test}
```